# Getting profile picture in Microsoft Graph API finds nothing

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get the profile picture of users (and, ideally, the fallback initials with different-colored backgrounds in case they don't have one) using the [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/profilephoto), but I can't get it to respond with anything but 404 status and the following body (annoyingly also after a delay of 5-20 seconds):

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "1e7f0ca4-2cd4-4602-a903-b0bde1ec8ea0",
            "date": "2018-06-11T14:04:10"
        }
    }
}
```

I've even tried with the [online Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), but with the same results. I've uploaded a profile picture to my own account, but I still get the same results.

What could be the cause? Are there other ways to get at the profile picture of an Azure AD user?

Comment: Which endpoint are you calling (V1 vs. beta)? And what permissions have you set for the application? I recently created an application that _did_ read the profile picture successfully. So it can be done :) Could you share some relevant code?

Comment: I'm using the v1 endpoint, specifically https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value. I've tried activating every permission I could find that remotely relates to reading user data, but without different results.

Comment: @rickvdbosch Also, I'm perfectly able to get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/ so I doubt that it's a permissions problem...

Comment: OK. So you're calling the API directly, or are you using the SDK? Will share my working code later.

Comment: I'm calling the API correctly. But I'm getting the same results with the graph explorer online, where I basically just open up the web UI and click "my profile photo" in the examples section on the left.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsoft Graph v1.0 retrieves the user's `profilePhoto` from Exchange Online, not Azure Active Directory. As such, users that don't have a mailbox provisioned in Exchange Online will not have a `profilePhoto` available.

From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/profilephoto):

> A profile photo of a user, group or an Outlook contact accessed from Exchange Online. It's binary data not encoded in base-64.

In the `/beta` endpoint, the `profilePhoto` resource was expanded to include both Exchange and AAD. From the [Beta documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/profilephoto):

> A profile photo of a user, group or an Outlook contact accessed from Exchange Online or Azure Active Directory (AAD). It's binary data not encoded in base-64.

There isn't an ETA on when this functionality will be released on the `/v1.0` endpoint and, in most cases, I would caution against using `/beta` functionality in a production. I have however seen several developers use `/beta` fallback option for fetching a `profilePhoto`: If the `/v1.0` endpoint fails to return a photo, a subsequent call is made to `/beta` to check if there is an AAD image available. This is a relatively safe use of the beta endpoint as your app isn't pulling a hard dependency on a beta API.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies a lot! In my use case, none of the users have a mailbox set up, so there's very little reason to call the `/1.0` API for this at the moment. And since the `/1.0` endpoint takes ~20 seconds to respond, and I'm reluctant to add in a call that expensive that I know will fail just to be future-safe...

Comment: Also, is there a way to get this API to return the fallback avatars (initials with a background color) instead of 404 when no picture has been uploaded?

Comment: No, this would be something your application needs to handle. There are several packages out there that provide this functionality. Take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/initials-avatar-generator for example.

Comment: It’s ridiculous that this functionality is _still_ in beta even three years later. Thanks for the answer!