# How to update the profile picture, hireDate and birthday for a newly created user using MS Graph

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

So I'm building a SharePoint webpart that can update and create new users into the Azure AD.

The editing part works fine, but I am having trouble creating a new user namely I cant upload a the profile image nor update the `birthday` or `hireDate` fields.

When I try to update the dates for the newly created AD user I get

```
Microsoft.Office.Server.Directory.DirectoryObjectUnauthorizedAccessException
```

Though the webpart can edit for other users.
This is the body of the request:

```
{birthday: "2020-11-03T22:00:00.000Z", hireDate: "2020-11-18T22:00:00.000Z"}
```

Now with the image I found this answer:
[Getting profile picture in Microsoft Graph API finds nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799704/getting-profile-picture-in-microsoft-graph-api-finds-nothing/50801844) (TLTR: The user needs to have an Exchange Online mailbox to be able to add a profile image.)

But I have no idea how to create the mailbox for the new user using Graph API and can't find anything useful from Google. Seams like it would be possible, but I have no starting point.

**Edit**
The end point I use to update the newly created user's is:

```
PATCH
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UserId}/
```

The user was created using MS Graph API as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-1-create-a-user

Note that I can update other users so it should not be a rights issue.

**Edit 2**

So I found out that you can change the `hireDate` and `birthday` for the following endpoint only:

```
PATCH
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/
```

When you try to change them for other users then other then yourself then you get the error above, so this is a rights issue i.e. the following endpoint does not work (unless the UserId corresponds to you)

```
PATCH
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{UserId}/
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to create mailboxes in Office 365, then you have two options to consider Exchange PowerShell's New-Mailbox command or Exchange Admin Center (EAC) using UI. Unfortunately there is no Microsoft Graph API available for it.
- Here's the documentation for it - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/create-user-mailboxes
- Also you can automate [Exchange PowerShell with .Net framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps#connect-to-exchange-online-powershell-by-using-mfa) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this endpoint to update user birthday and hireDate.

```
PATCH /users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

Document address:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

My test result for your reference:
[image]
[image]

Updated:
[image]

Comment: yes that works for me as well, it is just when I create a new user then that does not work on users that I created with Graph API as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http I guess I should have specified that I am already using that endpoint

Comment: These two attributes cannot be used in the post request. The error reported when I added these two attributes is：The following properties cannot be set in the initial POST request. Please set them in a subsequent PATCH request: birthday, hireDate

Comment: I am already doing that from my own testing I found that you need a separate PATCH request to update those fields even for users that where not created by Graph API, the issue I am having is only with newly created users that where created using Graph API

Comment: So I found out that `birthday` and `hireDate` fields can only be changed by the user who is that user. That is why the editing worked for me before I only tested on my own account, an ideas what right I need to change them for other users as well